# Android. OpenGL ES draw screen size square in ortho projection

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm new in openGL ES. I read simple tutorials but i have problem with setup Ortho and draw screen size square. Could you provide simple code as example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice usage of the orthographic projection is that you can specify how big influence a single float will have in your application when you're setting your vertex data.

For example, consider this explanation:

```
float right = 5.0f
float top = 4.0f
glOrthof(0.0f, right, 0.0f, top);
```

[image: Example image]

In the image above; an object that has a quad (built from triangles) whose size is equal to 1 *also* corresponds to one of the squares.

Shortly, it doesn't matter which values you pass into the `glOrtho()` height and right arguments as long as you are setting correct float values in your vertices, which should correspond to one square.