# Finding the edge of the screen android

Tags: android, opengl-es, collision-detection, viewport

This may sound really obvious but how can I find the points along the edge of the screen in order to know if a moving object has hit the edge of the screen.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have orthographic projection, you can easily know where your edges are by knowing the values you've passed into the `glOrtho()` function.

For example, consider this line:

```
glOrtho(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Here you can *decide* how big influence a single float will have in your program. You can find more information about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735411/android-opengl-es-draw-screen-size-square-in-ortho-projection/6740300#6740300).

However, in this scenario your left edge is 0.0 and your bottom edge is 0.0. Your top edge is defined by *height* and your right edge is defined by *width*.

In this way you don't have to rely on a specific screen size since your world will always be as big as you define. For example, you don't need to define the orthographical width and height by the *width* and *height* parameters, but instead use some data telling your application how big your world should be.

Comment: hang on does gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height) return the width and height of the screen?

Comment: With the `glViewport()` call you are telling OpenGL where you render your information on your screen.

Comment: How about `gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);` with viewport being `int viewport[4]` is that correct? because with these variables glOrthof seems to return a blank screen. =(

Comment: @Jack: `glGetIntegerv()` is not for setting up the viewport, or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: so the command you've given me? Do I put that in as it is or do I need to replace height and width with something

Comment: even with that my screen appears blank. Hmm what should the coordinates be at the bottom left of the screen?

Comment: All this depends on how you want your world. If your want it to be 10 float, put in 10 float as the top and right arguments. If you want it to be something else, just put that into the function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: Within the context of OpenGL (as the tag implies) this won't work effectively since the coordinate space of the opengl view is different than the parent view AND the open gl view might not span the entire screen.